# ReactJS - Material UI - FlexGrow is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to implement FlexBox, but I don't seem to understand how to use flexGrow. I tried the following code but the background just wraps around content.

Could someone point me in the right direction? I'm using React 17.0.2 and Material UI library

```
<Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
  <Navbar />
  <Box
    sx={{
      backgroundColor: "#EAECEE",
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "center",
      flexGrow: 1,
    }}
  >
    content
  </Box>
</Box>
```

[image]

```
<Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
  <Navbar />
  <Box
    sx={{
      backgroundColor: "#EAECEE",
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "center",
      height: "700px",
    }}
  >
    content
  </Box>
</Box>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I needed to add a height to the container Box like so:

```
<Box sx={{ height: "100vh", display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
  <Navbar />
  <Box
    sx={{
      backgroundColor: "#EAECEE",
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "center",
      flexGrow: 1,
    }}
  >
    content
  </Box>
</Box>
```